# Textview.setText is not working in textwatcher class inside adapter class

Tags: android, textwatcher, listview-adapter

I want to set countdown timer value to textview on aftertextchanged method of MytextWatcher all this happenes when user enter some text into edittext but value is not setting to textview.
Here is my code:

in adapter class:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
           /* LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/
            View rowView = view;
            if (rowView == null) {

                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_visitorlist, null);



                TextView edtxtotp = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.edtxtotp);

                txttimer = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txttimer);


                edtxtotp.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(edtxtotp) );
```

in textwatcher class

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            EditText edtxtotp = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtxtotp);
            //final TextView txttimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttimer);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hi"+otp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(edtxtotp.getText().toString().length()>=4) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new CountDownTimer(60000,1000)
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        txttimer.setText("testing");
                        counter--;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        txttimer.setText("Finish");
                    }
                }.start();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Maximum level reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: remove `CountDownTimer`

Comment: First of all your creating your countdown time in aftertextchange method which wrong as everytime the method gets called you are creating a new object of your countdown time.

Comment: actually as soon as user enters some value  in edittext the timer should start

Comment: then change your condition from edtxtotp.getText().toString().length()>=4 to edtxtotp.getText().toString().length() < 4

Comment: How to get the txttimer defination in MyTextWatcher class as i m able to see  is that MyTextWatcher  class does not get the the initializationof txttimer .